# Not getting hiddenfield value in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an issue in getting the hidden field values, which is been set in page load at code behind. Problem is when i try to get that set values in javascript its giving undefined or null. Not able to get the values which was set in page load at code behind.

```
//cs code is like this
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

HiddenField_alt_edit.Value = "[{"unitid":"3072","unit_nameeng":"BOTTLE","purchcost":"2.000","salrate":"4.000","avgcost":"2.000","factor":"2"},{"unitid":"3073","unit_nameeng":"PKT","purchcost":"10.000","salrate":"20.000","avgcost":"10.000","factor":"10"}]";

ClientScriptManager script = Page.ClientScript;
                            script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", "<script type=text/javascript>addAlternativeRowWithData();</script>");

}
```

```
//aspx page declaration goes like this. Also i am using a master page.
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_alt_edit" runat="server"  Value="i am on."/>

</asp:Content>
```

```
// javascript file code goes like this
function addAlternativeRowWithData(mode) 
{

    alert("test");
    var idvalue = $("#HiddenField_alt_edit").val();
    alert(idvalue);
    alert($nonconfli('#ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField_alt_edit').val());
    var myHidden = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField_alt_edit.ClientID %>').value;
    alert(myHidden);
    var json_string = $nonconfli('#ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField_alt_edit').val();
    var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(json_string);
    alert("test 2");
    alert(arr_from_json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The id generated at client side can differ as the Hidden field is server side control in your code as you have set `runat="server"`.

There are two ways normally. Either make the `ClientIDMode` static or use the instance in form to get client side id.

Like:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_alt_edit" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server"  
                 Value="i am on."/>
```

and then following should work:

```
var idvalue = $("#HiddenField_alt_edit.ClientID").val();
```

or in client side code you need to get id like below:

```
var idvalue = $("#<%= HiddenField_alt_edit.ClientID %>").val();
```

Comment: I tried your solution sir, but the result was same as which i was getting before. All values undefined. Will do one thing will create a fresh test page and check how this will work.

Comment: What i understood from the scenario is that i am using the web form technology. So when i use the same javascript code in another page **(but this aspx page uses another master page)** so its working. so this error is happening from the master page which i have added. I now have no clew to what difference i should look in these master pages

Answer (score 0):

Change: 
`HiddenField_alt_edit.Value = [{"unitid":"3072","unit_nameeng":"BOTTLE","purchcost":"2.000","salrate":"4.000","avgcost":"2.000","factor":"2"},{"unitid":"3073","unit_nameeng":"PKT","purchcost":"10.000","salrate":"20.000","avgcost":"10.000","factor":"10"}]`

To this:
`HiddenField_alt_edit.Value = "
[{'unitid':'3072','unit_nameeng':'BOTTLE','purchcost':'2.000','salrate':'4.000','avgcost':'2.000','factor':'2'},{'unitid':'3073','unit_nameeng':'PKT','purchcost':'10.000','salrate':'20.000','avgcost':'10.000','factor':'10'}]"`

Then, add this:
`<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_alt_edit" runat="server"  Value="i am on."  ClientIDMode="Static" />`

In you js, you have to put this:

```js
const value = document.getElementById('HiddenField_alt_edit').value

const jsonString = JSON.stringify(value)
const json = JSON.parse(jsonString)

console.log(json)
```

```html
<input hidden id="HiddenField_alt_edit" value="[{'unitid':'3072','unit_nameeng':'BOTTLE','purchcost':'2.000','salrate':'4.000','avgcost':'2.000','factor':'2'},{'unitid':'3073','unit_nameeng':'PKT','purchcost':'10.000','salrate':'20.000','avgcost':'10.000','factor':'10'}]">
```

Comment: I tried this also, but the result was same as which i was getting before. All values undefined.

Comment: Inspect the input with the inspector and check if the value is set. I think the value is not getting set right.

Comment: When i am inspecting the element its showing value. But what ever i do it doesn't comes to JS file.

Comment: What i understood from the scenario is that i am using the web form technology. So when i use the same javascript code in another page **(but this aspx page uses another master page)** so its working. so this error is happening from the master page which i have added. I now have no clew to what difference i should look in these master pages –

Comment: You can see de name of the section. When you use a MasterPage and the control doesn't have the property: ClientIDMode="Static". ASP set the id of the section before the real id. So, if you have id="hiddenValue" and the name of section is "bodySection" the control id becomes "bodySection_hiddenValue". Again, to avoid this you should put ClientIDMode="Static" in your control attributes.